# Gitlab, Clean Up policies docker images

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have a repostory in Gitlab, which generate a docker container on every build, for testing, and these images could be discarded because they are temporal build (Eg, Merge Request and others)

The images are storage in the following format:

```
registry.gitlab.com/mygroup/docker-images/nodejs-and-tools/build:175-16-alpine-523e4c0b415c47956ec4b17e9ceba787ae503e8a

registry.gitlab.com/mygroup/docker-images/nodejs-and-tools/build:175-16.15.1-alpine-523e4c0b415c47956ec4b17e9ceba787ae503e8a

registry.gitlab.com/mygroup/docker-images/nodejs-and-tools/build:175-18-alpine-523e4c0b415c47956ec4b17e9ceba787ae503e8a
```

And I have set up the remove tags with the following configuration.

```
**Remove these tags
Remove tags older than 60 days
Remove tags matching: .*/build:.*
```

But never update any tag; I assume the error is in the Regex, but I try multiple formats without any success.